# Android 8 (Oreo) WifiManager reconnect method times out

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-8.0-oreo

I am having an issue. The app I am busy with has a strange issue at the moment. I use the following library: [WiseFly](https://github.com/isuPatches/WiseFy) which is a simple wifi manager wrapper

My app manages WiFi networks. It will add to saved networks and connects to it depending on users interaction with my app. It works perfectly on all versions of android, except for  Android Oreo on my Pixel.

It times out on the following line internally on the wrapper:

```
getWifiManager().disconnect();
getWifiManager().enableNetwork(wifiConfiguration.networkId, true);
getWifiManager().reconnect();
```

The last line is the issue. And if I go into the network settings on android, I see the saved network, but will also not connect from within android. Any ideas what I could look for to fix this issue?

This is the code used to add the network:

```
/**
     * To generate a configuration for a WPA2 network
     *
     * @param ssid The ssid for the WPA2 network's configuration
     * @param password The password for the WPA2 network's configuration
     *
     * @return WifiConfiguration - The WPA2 network configuration
     */
    public WifiConfiguration generateWPA2NetworkConfiguration(String ssid, String password) {
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
        wifiConfiguration.SSID = mSSIDUtil.convertSSIDForConfig(ssid);
        wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = "\"" + password + "\"";
        wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
        wifiConfiguration.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);

        wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
        wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        return wifiConfiguration;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: No, unfortunately not yet. Still trying to find the solution

Comment: Still searching for solutions?

Comment: try to close this section //getWifiManager().disconnect();

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// Allow a previously configured network to be associated with.
getWifiManager().enableNetwork(wifiConfiguration.networkId, true);

// Reconnect to the currently active access point, if we are currently disconnected.
getWifiManager().reconnect();

// wait until reconnect process is completed
Thread.sleep(3000);
```